# will data be synced among all instances when use mongodb statefulset

Tags: kubernetes

Take this case https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/ for example (suppose we need write to the database).
Is the data synced among each mysql isntance?
If not, if there is any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

> Is the data synced among each mysql isntance?

**Disclaimer**: although question title is centered around mongodb this answer is directed to your actual question (given example StatefulSet and mysql).

**Yes.** The StatefulSet in [the link you provided](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/) is keeping one master pod and two read-only pods in sync.

Notes:

- Services are configured in such a way that any pod will handle read operation (both master and any read-only-slave) while write operation must be done by writing to master pod exclusively since read-only-slaves are configured (using ConfigMap) to reject write operations.
- InitContainers are used in each pod to distinguish configuration between master and read-only-slaves, as well as to do initial data load on restart.
- Each mysql pod is consisting of two containers: mysql and xtrabackup. xtrabackup is tasked with syncing data with the master.
- As noted in the documentation:

  ```
  this is not a production configuration. 
  In particular, MySQL settings remain on insecure defaults
  to keep the focus on general patterns for running stateful applications in Kubernetes.
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. if we need to read and write to both sql master and its slaves. this would cause some problem, right?  but

Comment: You won’t be able to write to slaves ConfigMap made sure of that. From link you provided: “in this case, you want the master to be able to serve replication logs to slaves and you want slaves to reject any writes that don’t come via replication.”